# Spark Dataframe loosing data to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a spark dataframe thats has the cleansed data. I have a total of 512 records in the data frame.
Before I write to the S3, I am repartitioning to a single file since my total number of records are low and I want to keep the number of partitions less.

```
val t =tripAttributesDF.repartition(1)
t.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv")
.save("s3://<Bucket>/Trips_Detail_Table/csv/valid_trips_csv")
```

The DataFrame count shows correctly as follows
       scala> t.count()
       res32: Long = 512

But when I open the CSV file I have only 34 rows. Not 512 as I expected.

I looked hard in all posts, and no one seems to have encountered this issue.
I am using Spark 2.2

Please help if anyone knows the answer

Thanks

Comment: Can you update how you are opening the csv, and  a command to show the record count in output folder. Also, try coalesce(1) in place of repartition(1). if it helps

Comment: I am opening the CSV as follows. val dfTrip = spark.read.option("header","false").schema(schemaTrip).csv("s3://<Bucket>/pocsd_rawUploadCsv/"). Than I apply a schema using Array of StructType. I have a total of 128 columns in the CSV. I am creating new DF's for filtering data as well as applying window operations on the file.

Comment: @Amit, Thank you. I tried using coalesce(1) and repartition(1). The behavior was the same. See below, as it seems that it was entirely my typo.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I am going to answer my own question. This was entirely my fault. I am enforcing a schema on the file, and one of the fields that I need in my final DF is of type Double. I was enforcing an IntegerType and it looks like Spark 2.2 simply truncated the data. There were no errors. When I tried on Spark 2.11, I was able to debug.